# Apache can't save files to mounted directory

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, php, mount, cifs

I have bought WD myCloud storage and I have mount it to centos 7 by adding this line to fstab

```
\\wd_mycloud_ip_address\shared_folder /backup cifs rw,suid,username=shared_folder_username,password=shared_folder_password 0 0
```

after that i mount using

```
# mount -a
```

it works fine, and I am able to insert/create/delete files into the /backup which is mirrored into the WD storage
Note that the directory /backup has chown root:root

the problem now when I want to let the apache (using php web application) itself save files into the mounted directory /backup , I am getting an error in my web application "The destination folder is not writable."

I tried diffrent senario to solve the issue but unfortuntly it dosen't works fine.

First I have umount the /backup, changed the

```
chown -R apache:apache /backup
```

, the web application is able to save the files. but the problem this only when I umount.

second, while the /backup is mounted with "chown root:root", I have tried to change it is owner/group to apache:apache but it doesn't allow. the commend goes without an error but when I "ls -al" it show me it is still root:root.

How can I mount a /backup directory using root:root and at the same time let the web application save files into /backup using apache:apache ?

Comment: Try to create a folder beneath `/backup` like `/backup/apache` and try to `chown apache:apache /backup/apache` and use that one.

Comment: @Thomas I have created new dir under /backup, and I have run chown -R /backup/apache still it not able to change to apache:apache  .. when I run ls -al it shows root:root ... That means the mount affect all inner directories as well.

Comment: Given its CentOS the mount most probably has the wrong selinux security context.

Answer (score 0):

I have added apache uid and gid to the mount statement and deleted suid as following

> \wd_mycloud_ip_address\shared_folder /backup cifs rw,uid=apache_user_id,gid=apache_group_id,username=shared_folder_username,password=shared_folder_password 0 0